# i am not able to connect to the application hosted on port 80

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-server-2012

I am trying to access an application that is hosted on port 80. When i try the url from my personal computer , the site is not reachable but the same url on the server( which hosts the application) i am able to access the site.

When i disable the firewall then i am able to access the site from my pc. So there is some rule which is blocking this port. How do i determine what windows firewall  rule is blocking this port. I have disables IIS as well.

Kindly point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions Microsoft provides for opening a port on Windows firewall?

You can find them here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934283.aspx

Also, you will need to ensure you open the rule for all applicable firewall profiles (more information can be found here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/getting-started-wfas-firewall-profiles-ipsec(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: r3mus thanks for the answer. i made a mistake while creating an inbound rule for the port.Now it is working well

Comment: Great stuff! Glad it's working for you.